# Large-Scale-Structure (LSS) and the Fingers-of-God

Tags: astronomy, cosmology, observable-universe, virial-theorem

In the Large-Scale-Structure (LSS) artifacts named [fingers-of-god](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingers_of_God) are apparent in the redshift space and justified by

> "The large velocities that lead to this effect are associated with the
>   gravity of the cluster by means of the virial theorem; they change the
>   observed redshifts of the galaxies in the cluster"

There are [few references, (Jackson 1972) (*)](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1972MNRAS.156P...1J), and [Annu. Rev. Astron. Astrophys. 1988. 26: 631-86](http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Sept01/Bahcall/Bahcall8.html)  in the WP article and I do no understand how the radial direction preference is justified and I could not find any source.

I've never heard of a N-Body simulation on Large Scale able to reproduce those artifacts. Am I correct?
Can anyone make this issue more clear, please ?

(*) it is more a no-go than an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a cluster of galaxies at a "spatial" redshift of $z=0.5$.  The galaxies in the cluster are swirling around each other, much like the stars of a star cluster.  The velocities are broadly spread out in all directions but the line-of-sight velocity leads to a Doppler shift.  Now, if all you measure is change in frequency of spectral features relative to some lab standard, then your measurement is a superposition of the "distance" redshift (i.e. redshift because the object is far away and space is expanding) and the "velocity" redshift (i.e. redshift because of Doppler shifting from line-of-sight velocity in the potential of the cluster).

When you plot the galaxies of your cluster, you'll find that, instead of all sitting at $z=0.5$, they will occupy a spread in redshift space but the same point on the sky. That's because the tangential velocity doesn't contribute to the redshift at all: only the line-of-sight component does so only the redshift-direction is elongated into fingers.

This would probably make much more sense with a diagram but some quick Googling didn't get me anywhere.